# Converting vector to numeric and character in one go

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and wanted to know if there is any way to convert multiple vectors/variables into a desired 'class' (e.g. 3 variables within a dataset are factors, and I want to convert these 3 into numerical variables in one go).

Below is the dataset which contains columns `"Product"` as `chr` and the remaining columns  as `factor`s, however I want to keep `"Product"` and `"Month"` as character and `"Sales"` and `"Profit"` as numeric.

```
str(Conditional_function_IVY)

'data.frame':   100 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Product: chr  "Bellen" "Bellen" "Sunshine" "Sunset" ...
 $ Month  : Factor w/ 12 levels "April","August",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 ...
 $ Sales  : Factor w/ 88 levels " ? 501.00 "," ? 504.00 ",..: 8 13 64 16 55 78 81 29 2 52 ...
 $ Profit : Factor w/ 65 levels " ? 100.00 "," ? 101.00 ",..: 44 34 5 15 39 16 37 38 65 56 ...
```

I've done it in the following way but it consumes a lot of time, hence I am wondering if there is any way which would let me do this in one go.

```
Conditional_function_IVY$Month=as.character(Conditional_function_IVY$Month)
> Conditional_function_IVY$Sales=as.numeric(Conditional_function_IVY$Sales)
> Conditional_function_IVY$Profit=as.numeric(Conditional_function_IVY$Profit)
> str(Conditional_function_IVY)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Product: chr  "Bellen" "Bellen" "Sunshine" "Sunset" ...
 $ Month  : chr  "January" "January" "January" "January" ...
 $ Sales  : num  8 13 64 16 55 78 81 29 2 52 ...
 $ Profit : num  44 34 5 15 39 16 37 38 65 56 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way of fixing this is at the time of date frame creation/import, more modern approaches from the *tidyverse* such as `readr` and `tibble` deal well with guessing column types and don't convert automatically to factor.

If that is not an option for you then you can transform with `dplyr::mutate` quite simply.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

Conditional_function_IVY %<>%
  mutate(
    Month = as.character(Month),
    Sales = as.numeric(as.character(Sales)),
    Profit = as.numeric(as.character(Profit))
  )
```

However, I notice you have some very strange values visible in your structure where your numeric values are stored. These could be stripped back to numeric using `gsub`.

*e.g.* `as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", " ? 501.00 ")) # [1] 501`

#### With two rows of your data

Using the two rows of your own data that I can derive from your question.

```
Conditional_function_IVY <- data.frame(
  Product = rep("Bellen", 2),
  Month = c("April", "August"),
  Sales = c(" ? 501.00 ", " ? 504.00 "),
  Profit = c(" ? 100.00 ", " ? 101.00 ")
)

Conditional_function_IVY %>%
  mutate(
    Month = as.character(Month),
    Sales = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", as.character(Sales))),
    Profit = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", as.character(Profit)))
  )

#   Product  Month Sales Profit
# 1  Bellen  April   501    100
# 2  Bellen August   504    101
```

Comment: Excellent Kevin - Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I like Kevin's approach, except that I dislike the copy/paste/editing of `as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", as.character(...))`. If you had even 10 columns this would be tedious, if you had 100 columns it would be utterly impractical. I would define a little utility functon and do something like this:

```
# define helper function
sub_convert = function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", as.character(...))

# using base R
to_convert = names(Conditional_function_IVY)[sapply(Conditional_function_IVY, is.factor)]
Conditional_function_IVY[to_convert] = lapply(
    Conditional_function_IVY[to_convert],
    sub_convert
)

# or using dplyr
library(dplyr)
Conditional_function_IVY = mutate_if(
    Conditional_function_IVY,
    is.factor,
    sub_convert
)
```

This scales better and also has the advantage that if you need to tweak the `sub_convert` function you only need to edit it in one place, instead of every time it is used.

Comment: I like your function to generalise the text cleaning and agree my approach may be tedious with many columns. However, I also tend to follow Hadley's rule of thumb to write a function after more than a few (3) repeats.